# Arista and "Unparalleled Performance with Dynamic Deep Buffers and VOQ for Lossless forwarding"

Tags: arista

Arista advertises "Unparalleled Performance with Dynamic Deep Buffers and VOQ for Lossless forwarding".  My employer is trialing a switch which advertises gigabytes of port buffers.  How are these implemented?  Is this kind of RAM of a higher latency that traditional port buffers?

Comment: When data are buffered, then the latency must increase. Basically, this allows a longer line, but the line moves no faster.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes maybe I should add color to my question. We are trialing this switch for media production where a ‘traditional’ switch was overrun with micro bursting. We are wondering about the deep buffers implementation because it breaks our mental model of how deep storing of these packets will have a fundamentally different effect than the drops and retransmits we are dealing with today. Perhaps delayed in order delivery is still preferable than drops when it comes to storage? Still curious about implementation.

Comment: Shared buffer? Per-port buffer? Type of memory? Speed of memory bus? Ultimately, this is a discussion you need to have with Arista. If you have a lot of drops due to bursts, more buffer space *could* help, but it could just as likely hurt. Only way to know is try it.

Comment: Seconding both comments: as the used queue depth increases, latency must also increase - that has little relevance for microbursts, but really hurts with a bottlenecked network as you get dropped packets *and* buffer bloating. Do make sure your network is properly designed and interconnected. Reasonable oversizing *really* helps with most congestion issues and most often pays off at the end.

Comment: @Zac67 May you elaborate on

> that has little relevance for microbursts

To the best of our knowledge, our problem is micro bursts-specific and not a "general" bottleneck.

Comment: @YoloPerdiem Well, _micro_bursts either get buffered (large queues) or dropped (small buffers) - buffering is obviously more desirable; it increases latency but dropped packets are worse. If bursts get longer than the queue can buffer because of real bottlenecks you lose data anyway.

Comment: Thank you.  That just leaves the question of what is it about the implementation that they have a multi-gigabyte-of-port-buffers switch that is cost competitive with other vendors' 12MB; what are the gotchas.  There is no free lunch.

Comment: Talk to Arista. In my experience they’re more than happy to discuss things like this.